# Is there a way to use a specific DNS for a specific domain?

Tags: domain-name-system

At work we use OpenDNS and it has wrongly blocked irc.freenode.net for malware. How can I make sure that any request for *.freenode.net goes to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google's DNS).

I tried doing this by fiddling with resolv.conf on Ubuntu, but I wasn't able to get too far. Also, is there an easy way to do this for Mac and Windows systems (I have a few colleagues using those OSes and they'd like to use IRC as well).

Comment: Be careful - attempting to get around security controls can get one escorted out of some companies.  Also, it is possible other DNS servers are blocked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Linux does not support the use of domain-specific DNS servers via `resolv.conf`.  You could potentially work around this by running a caching nameserver (such as `BIND` or `dnsmasq`) locally and then configuring explicit forwarders for each domain.

Under OS X, this sort of setting is relatively easy using the `scutil` command.  The common use case for this configuration is to forward DNS requests for a VPN connection to VPN-specific DNS servers, so you'll find this discussed often in concert with, e.g., OpenVPN.  [This document](https://www.afp548.com/2005/07/17/using-scutil-to-set-dns-server/) talks about the `scutil` command as does [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050621051643993), and a Google search for `openvpn` and `scutil` will yield more results.

I'm not sure about Windows.  You could presumably use the local DNS server solution for all three platforms if you needed to.

Comment: Is this still true in the `systemd-resolved` world? (Yes I realize your answer is 7 years old)

Comment: @Pointy It seems recent versions of systemd-resolved can handle this: https://gist.github.com/brasey/fa2277a6d7242cdf4e4b7c720d42b567#solution

Comment: Windows can do it using NRPT rules: `Add-DnsClientNrptRule -Namespace "example.com" -NameServers "203.0.113.1"`

Answer (score 43):

This can't be done with the standard DNS resolution provided by *nix (and Windows AFAIK), you need your own DNS server to do this. On *nix [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is the best choice for this, and you can either run this on every workstation or run it on a server and configure all the workstations to use this.

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
server=/freenode.net/8.8.8.8
server=/freenode.net/8.8.4.4
```

Comment: This can absolutely be done using the standard DNS resolution provided by *some* operating systems.  Just not by Linux.

Comment: To control  which interface to use I added the ```@vpn0```  at the end of the DNS servers. This can be useful to use it only when a VPN is up.

Answer (score 16):

Under OS X you can use files like /etc/resolver/example.com with content:

```
nameserver 172.16.5.5
```

to forward dns requests for *.example.com to 172.16.5.5

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004062902195410

Comment: Does this apply for High Sierra ?

Comment: It still works on Mojave

Answer (score 10):

You can do it on Windows with PowerShell:

`Add-DnsClientNrptRule -Namespace "pqr.com" -NameServers "10.0.0.1"`

Reference:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/add-dnsclientnrptrule?view=win10-ps

Comment: It's a pity that no support for wilcard namespace.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to use [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) --dns option for this. For example:

```
firejail --dns=8.8.8.8 firefox
```

This way dns server can be set per application instead of per domain. So it might be a better solution in some circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

I did this on Fedora by installing a local DNS server.

first install bind:

```
sudo dnf install bind
```

step 1: append a line to `/etc/named.conf` (as root):

```
include "/etc/named/freenode.net.conf";
```

step 2: create the zone file `/etc/named/freenode.net.conf` (as root):

```
zone "freenode.net" {
    type forward;
    forwarders { 8.8.8.8; };
};
```

now restart named:

```
sudo service named restart
```

now reconfigure your lan settings to use 127.0.0.1 as the DNS server, rather than the DCHP-allocated hosts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows DNS Manager for most of your domain when accessed locally, but want to delegate one host (or for a few, if you repeat the steps below) to an external DNS provider, then you can do the following:

- First delete any previous local `A` or `CNAME` record for the hostname you are going to delegate

  - These are found in the main window for 'DNS Manager/dc-name/Forward Lookup Zones'
- Then right-click on your forward lookup zone, e.g. 'DNS Manager/dc-name/Forward Lookup Zones/foo.com', and select 'New Delegation...'
- Fill in the delegated domain for the single host you want to delegate, e.g. `mail.foo.com`
- In the next step, populate one on more nameserver names, each with one or more IP addresses (IP addresses are required here, and I assume this means they are not dynamically looked up in future, unfortunately)

  - You can look up these values, e.g. on an external Linux machine, using: `whois foo.com` (note, not `mail.foo.com`) to find the nameserver(s) (you should look or `grep` for lines starting with `Name Server`); then `host ns1.mydnscompany.com` (for example) to find the ip address(es) of the name server(s)
- Finish the wizard, everything should now be set up

  - As normal, you may need to run `ipconfig /flushdns` on a client if you want to see the changes immediately
  - If the delegation does not show up in DNS Manager (immediately below the forward lookup zone in the navigation tree), even after right-click 'Refresh' to refresh the DNS Manager view, try re-checking the first step

Answer (score 0):

We are encountering similar requirements when connecting with OpenVPN, and OpenVPN provides a solution known as split-DNS (https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-dns-resolution-problems/). This feature allows the resolution of specific domains over the VPN DNS server, while other domains are resolved via the local DNS server.

To enable split-DNS, the following directives should be included in either your OpenVPN server or client configuration:

```shell
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
dhcp-option DOMAIN freenode.net
```

I have tested these options on macOS, and they work well. However, on Linux, you need to use the script available at https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved